# How to set vector one line vector assignment?

Tags: matlab, matrix

I want to do the following in Matlab:

```
[nnz_rows, nnz_cols] = find(messages_matrix);
nnz_matrix_points = [nnz_rows, nnz_cols];
```

I want `nnz_matrix_points` to be a `2xn` vector containing the index that find returns, but I want to do it on one line. I tried to search online, with no success.

Comment: I don't have matlab here but maybe something like `[x(:,1), x(:,2)] = find(mtx)`  ?

Comment: Why do you want to do it in one line?  What special computational advantage do you gain by doing this in one line instead of two?   Doing it this way is more readable IMHO.

Comment: This seems to work. But maybe there is a simpler solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[nnz_matrix_points(1, :) nnz_matrix_points(2, :)] = find(messages_matrix);
```

produces a `2xN` matrix.

```
[nnz_matrix_points(:, 1) nnz_matrix_points(:, 2)] = find(messages_matrix);
```

produces a `Nx2` matrix.

Comment: @rayryeng Thanks for catching my mistake.

Comment: No problem :) BTW +1.